# How do I perform BDD test for spring application when am running the the front end using another framework (vuejs) which is running on different port

Tags: java, spring-mvc, junit, bdd, cucumber-java

Am trying to perform BDD tests for my spring application. Am using vuejs for the front end which runs on different port.
My problem is that spring application is failing to connect to the front end application(returns 404 status)

Here is the code on how am connecting to the front end.

```
import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;
@ContextConfiguration(classes = MainApplication.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
public class PlantRequestSteps {

List<Plant> plants = new ArrayList<>();

@Autowired
private WebApplicationContext wac;

private WebClient customerBrowser;
HtmlPage customerPage;

@Autowired
PlantHireRepository plantHireRepository;


@Before
public void setUp() {

    customerBrowser = MockMvcWebClientBuilder.webAppContextSetup(wac).build();
}

@After
public void tearOff() {
    plantHireRepository.deleteAll();
    plants.clear();
}

@Given("^the following plants are vailable from this given date$")
public void the_following_plants_are_vailable_from_this_given_date(DataTable table){
    for (Map<String, String> row: table.asMaps(String.class, String.class)){
        plants.add(Plant.of(
                Long.parseLong(row.get("id")), row.get("name"),
                row.get("description"), new BigDecimal(row.get("price")),
                LocalDate.parse(row.get("date"))));
    }
}

@Given("^am on BuildIT's  \"([^\"]*)\" web page$")
public void am_on_BuildIT_s_web_page(String arg1) throws Throwable {
    customerPage = customerBrowser.getPage("http://localhost:8081/");
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve my problem by changing the testing library. Previously I was using **HtmlUnit** which only works when both the front end and back end are running on the same port(coupled together).

I used **selenium** and **chrome** driver which are independent of spring framework

Here is a basic setup ... .....

```
public class PlantRequestSteps  {

@Autowired
private WebApplicationContext wac;

private WebDriver driver ;;


static {
 // you should specify the path where you installed your chrome driver
// as the second parameter to this function 
  System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/path/chromedriver");
}


@Before
public void setup() {

    driver = new ChromeDriver();

}

@After
public void tearoff() {

   driver.close();

}

@Given("^ that am on this   \"([^\"]*)\" web page$")
public void that_am_on_this_web_page(String arg1) throws Throwable {
    driver.get("http://localhost:8081/");
}
```

Also do not forget to add the **selenium library** in addition to **Junit** library . Am using maveen so I added mine in the pom.xml file.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.11.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
        <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.9.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Finally make sure you have the latest version of chrome driver installed(the old version seems not work )